# elem.onlick for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add several links into a paragraph in Javascript. I am trying to add an `onclick` to each element but it only adds it to the first element created. My Javascript code is:

```
function addDrawing(url, html, id) {
  var elem = document.createElement('a');
  elem.id = id;
  elem.onclick = function() {tableauClicked(id)};
  fetch(url)
  .then( r => r.text() )
  .then(t => elem.innerText = t)
  html.appendChild(elem)
}
```

The code creates a new `a` element, gives it an id and an onclick event. The `fetch(url)` part gets text from a txt file to be displayed in the link. The link is added to the `html` paragraph. None of the ids are duplicated.

Comment: Try to make an example that we can see and use in jsfiddle

Comment: Not much to go on until we can reproduce the error. Please make that a part of your question so we can assist you. No need to reproduce the fetch part of this, I don't think that is the cause of the issue. A simple example will work just fine

Comment: A quick question; the "then" in fetch(url).then(r => r.text()) seems reasonable but the second "then" made me curious. Is r.text() returning a promise somehow? If not, how is it that the second then is executed?

Comment: I tried recreating it in jsfiddle but it seems to work there. My full projects is [here](https://repl.it/@NSCarter/Klondike)

Comment: @saglamcem `return`ing from `.then()` will invoke the next `.then()` function in the chain. `r => r.text()` implicitly returns `r.text()`, which is passed to the second `then()`. That all seems fine to me. [See demo](https://repl.it/repls/LittleExemplarySection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at your code, thanks for sharing, nice work.

the problem you are having with it is not in the addDrawing function.

the problem is in the prependDrawing function

```
function prependDrawing(url, html) {
  fetch(url)
  .then( r => r.text() )
  .then(t => html.innerHTML = t + html.innerHTML);
}
```

here you replace the innerHTML with a new value, which means the DOM is reevaluated and your original element is lost, sure you still see the HTML you created but the eventlistener `onclick` is lost.

fortunately this can easily be solved by using the .insertAdjacentHTML method instead.

```
function prependDrawing(url, html) {
  fetch(url)
  .then( r => r.text() )
  .then(t => html.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', t));
}
```

this may look a little strange but it will work.

> The insertAdjacentHTML() method of the Element interface parses the specified text as HTML or XML and inserts the resulting nodes into the DOM tree at a specified position. It does not reparse the element it is being used on, and thus it does not corrupt the existing elements inside that element. This avoids the extra step of serialization, making it much faster than direct innerHTML manipulation.

for the full docs check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Hope this helps.